# How to take screenshots of the full page or individual elements using the Firefox SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, screenshot, firefox-addon-sdk

As part of a Firefox addon, I'd like to be able to turn elements, iframes and the full page into a static image. I know this can be done [via the GCLI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI) with the screenshot command but I haven't been able to find a way to call this command (or equivalent) from the addon sdk.

For example, from the developer toolbar I can do this to get a screenshot of an element:

```
screenshot --selector #elementid
```

Or this to get a screenshot of the full page

```
screenshot --fullpage
```

Answer (score 0):

1. run a privileged [frame script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_parent)
2. locate the element
3. calculate its bounding rectangle
4. create a canvas
5. use [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawWindow) with the coordinates from the rectangle
6. send canvas image data or compressed image as blob to parent process